# Convert Hex to Byte array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, hex

I've a hardware which sends me a hex data and i need to convert it to byte array in swift. Here's example data;

```
01 01 02 0A 12 14 14 11 10 0D 0B 0A 09 09 08 08 08 07 06 06 06 06 06 06 05 05 06 05 05 04 04 04 04 03 03 03 04 
03 03 02 03 02 03 02 02 03 02 02 02 01 02 01 01 01 01 01
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

If you got a bunch of hexes (`UInt8`), then you can create `NSData` like this:

`NSData(bytes: [0xFF, 0xD9] as [UInt8], length: 2)`

Answer (score 0):

> use this method it gives Byte Array

```
func getByte(data:NSData) -> Array<UInt8> {
    let count = data.length / sizeof(Int8)
    var array = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)
    data.getBytes(&array, length:count * sizeof(UInt32))
    return array
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked for. He asked for the opposite. UInt8 is the input, NSdata is the output.